# Manage push notification's banner text

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I receiving push alert message in format "0;text;23". If app is active I can parse this message and show in alertView. It's possible to manage text in banner of push notification?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason that you don't use standard aps dictionary key-value pairs?

You can add there custom fields if you need and then parse them in app:

> {"aps":{"alert":"Your
>   Message","sound":"your_sound.wav","badge":"1"},"custom_key1":"value1","custom_key2":"value2"}

In such way your alert message will always be clean.

Comment: Ok, how can I show my string in push banner? In - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { method I can only set badge number. Is there a method that sets the string to notification center?

Comment: The question is - how manage and set my own text in notification center (banner on panel of swipe down on screen), not in alertView

Comment: I understood. You cannot set the text of Remote Notification banner from the App. It is backend work to send proper string via json payload.

Comment: Here the example if proper payload:

{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "custom_param1" : "bar",
    "custom_param2" : 42
}

"You got your emails." will be shown in notification banner.